# Flask-SQLalchemy returns None when attempting to execute SELECT query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a DB connected to the Flask App.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

DB contains table Names with 40 rows
[image]

Here's the model of the table:

```
class Names(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'names'
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    gender = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

Simple select-queries like this

```
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    print(db.session.connection())
    names = Names.query.all()
```

return None.

What am I doing wrong?

At the same time, when I read DB with a standard SQLAlchemy instead of Flask SQLAlchemy, it works:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db.db') 
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(session_factory)

name = session.query(Names).get(1) //returns row
print(name.name)
with app.app_context():
    name_flask = db.session.query(Names).get(1) //returns None
    print(name_flask)
```

Comment: did you use `print( names )` ?

Comment: Please show how you entered the rows in the Names table

Comment: @furas Yes, it prints an empty list

Comment: @Lenntror I entered the rows manually via SQLite Studio

Comment: @Lenntor However, it works correctly with the standard SQLAlchemy, so the problem should be somewhere in Flask

Comment: Could the problem be that you call `db.create_all()` at the beginning of the app_context?

Comment: Without `db.create_all()` works the same way

Comment: maybe you work with different file `db.db` and it has no data - especially if you use `db.create_all()` before

Comment: @furas no, I work with the same db. I can extract data from SQLAlchemy but not from Flask SQLAlchemy. Any suggestions why?

Comment: I suggest to check again if you really work with the same file - ie. rename database file and see if flask has problem to get file. And check again if you really have data in this database. If you run `db.create_all()` then it should remove all data and it has nothing to select.

Comment: now I see `flask` has `test.db` but `SQLAlchemy` has `db.db` - so you use different files.

Comment: @furas testdb was created to reduce the number of tables in db.db and basically contains only a single table from db.db (Names, actually).

Comment: so you use two different files - so they may have different contents. `table` may have empty table `Names`. Test code with original `db.db`

Comment: They don't because I have created test.db by coping db.db and removing all the tables except Names. Of course, I tested it with db.db as well. It doesn't work. What about some meaningful suggestions?

Comment: @Lenntror guys, come on, say something! This is a very urgent issue!

Comment: Are you using sqlalchemy 3.0? Then maybe try the new query interface `db.session.scalars(db.select(Names)).all()`. Does the issue persist if you add data via the `db.session.add` instead of entering them in sql studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurred because of the database location. When a database is called only by name specified in the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` parameter of the app, Flask attempts to detect the database in the `Instance` folder of the project. If it does not exist in that folder, Flask-SQLAlchemy creates a new one. While my database was located in the main folder of the project, the app created a new DB with the same name in the `Instances` folder and after tried to read it whereas it was obviously empty.

So far, check the database location.